# Run `docker compose` in GitLab pipeline

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I need to deploy an application stack to ECS. To do this, I use the new Docker Compose ECS integration (see e.g. [here](https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/)).

In few words, everything boils up to using the correct `docker context` and launching the command `docker compose up`. This is of great help and very quick.

I would like to automate the deploy process in a GitLab pipeline.

What (Docker) image should I use in my pipeline to be able to run the new `docker compose` command?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to elaborate on the idea from the comments:

The `docker compose` binary is direcly woven together with the `docker` command itself, essentially being an extension to it.

As I see it there are now two main options:

1. You setup a dedicated gitlab runner, that works with the normal shell executor. You then install docker on that machine and also setup the compose-cli according to [this](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/blob/main/INSTALL.md) manual. Then you can start deploying with the compose command.
2. You create a docker image that gives you the `docker compose` command. An example dockerfile could look like this:

```
FROM docker

RUN apk add curl
RUN apk add tar
RUN curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/releases/download/v1.0.6/docker-linux-amd64.tar.gz -O
RUN tar xzf docker-linux-amd64.tar.gz
RUN chmod +x docker/docker
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker /usr/bin/com.docker.cli
```

Now, the difficulty there is to manage to have the docker daemon available. However it should be possible with gitlabs [dind](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-the-docker-executor-with-the-docker-image-docker-in-docker) workflow.

After starting the container with `docker run --rm --privileged -it <containername> sh`
the `docker compose` command in my example would be available as `./docker compose` as I did not add the new docker binary to any path. However the docker daemon is not started.

**Note:** the resulting image from this Dockerfile is essentially only a modified Docker-in-Docker image. So it *should* work, but I was not able to test it.

<s>Docker itself provides an image on their docker hub that offers docker-compose functionality. The Gitlab CI image tag would be "docker/compose"</s>

https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose

Comment: Beware that the command is not `docker-compose`, but `docker compose`. Does the image work with the `ecs` Docker Context? From my tentatives, it seems no...

Comment: Ah yes, it seems I did not read your questions carefully enough. I did some more digging and what you would need is either "Docker Desktop" or manually install the so called "Compose CLI" on your machine. Alternatively you can build a new container that contains this Compose CLI. See info on their readme: https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/blob/main/INSTALL.md

You could base this new container on the already available dind (docker) images

Comment: Ok, thanks, interesting suggestion... Could you provide more details in your answer? Thanks.

Comment: Just create a DIND pipeline to run :)